# .net, C# Interface between Business Logic and DAL

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, data-access-layer, bll

I'm working on a small application from scratch and using it to try to teach myself architecture and design concepts.  It's a .NET 3.5, WPF application, and I'm using Sql Compact Edition as my data store.

I'm working on the business logic layer, and have just now begun to write the DAL.  I'm just using SqlCeComamnds to send over simple queries and SqlCeResultSet to get at the results.  I'm starting to design my Insert and Update methods, and here's the issue - I don't know the best way to get the necessary data from the BLL into the DAL.  Do I pass in a generic collection? Do I have a massive parameter list with all the data for the database? Do I simply pass in the actual business object (thus tying my DAL to the conrete stuff in the BLL?).

I thought about using interfaces - simply passing IBusinessObjectA into the DAL, which provides the simplicity I'm looking for without tying me TOO tightly to current implementations.  What do you guys think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I was in your position, I'd probably use LINQ to SQL to define my data access layer -  it'll save you lots of work maintaining all that SqlCeFooBar stuff and give you a designer (of sorts) for maintaining your database that you would otherwise lack, using SQL CE.

So in that case, I'd probably couple the business logic layer pretty tightly to the entities exposed by the L2S layer. The justification being that the entities *are* the business objects, albeit devoid of any services.

I probably wouldn't let the entities get as far up the hierarchy as the UI though. At that level, it makes much more sense to use a model specifically for the view - especially given that you're using WPF.

Of course, all of this depends upon the size and complexity of your application. I'm assuming it's a fairly small scale application (single user?) given that you're using SQL CE.

Comment: It's definitely a small, single-user app, but part of the reason I'm doing it is to get some practice at various design concepts, so I want to make sure the way I'm doing it is as close to the "correct" (most robust) design as possible.  Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is a simple answer to your questions because there are many options depending on the circumstances. I have found it helpful to read the two books below to help me understand the problems you describe better.

- MS .NET: Architecting Applications for the Enterprise (Esposito, Saltarello)
- MS Application Architecture Guide, 2nd edition.

The second book is available online. Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd673617.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

I think it is OK to pass the Business object to the Data Access Layer. I think the BLL's job is just to work with its objects, to check if all rules are being followed, about what can be saved, by whom, on what fields, time, etc.

Once it has done that it should pass it to the DAL, and I think it is IT'S job to figure out how to convert what it got into something that can be persisted, but it wont check what is being persisted or read or by whom, it will just do it. This could be straight foward, a la linq, but if your logic mdoels do not match your data model 1:1, then the DAL should do all the conversion.

About tying your DAL to the stuff in the BLL, I think you should worry about the other way around, tying your BLL to your DAL. I would use an interface to represent your DAL (as in IRepository) that way you can make your BLL call any kind of persistance mechanism just by changing the type of IRepository it is using (extra points if you use IoC :P). The concrete classes that implement the IRepository would be tied to the business objects, but they have to know what is it that they are saving don't they? while the BLL does NOT have to know what is doing the saving.

Comment: I think you're talking about the same thing I am, but coming at it from the other direction - I've always assumed the BLL converts raw data into business objects, whereas you suggest the DAL converts business objects into raw data.

Thanks for the post.  It made me think about the problem (Data <-> Objects) in a more holistic way, even if I don't end up going this route.

Answer (score 3):

To pass business object in the DAL is the simpler and fastest method. It works in small projects, but have same disadvantages:

1) Business Objects are part of BLL layer, and if you pass objects in BLL then DAL becomes dependent of BLL. low layer knows about upper one - this contradicts the idea of layers at all.

2) Business Object are usially very complex to save it directly in BD. In this case it is better to introduce new "Mappers" intermediate layer.

To overcome all these issues I usially make interface to DAL independent of Business Objects. I use "Row" classes instead - representation of one record in the database or XML. In .NET 3.5  linqtosql autogenerated classes can be used for this purpose.